# Can I calculate Churn Rate from Retention Rate?

Tags: churn

I am working on a model where some of the numbers need to derive from various data points.
I want to confirm if the churn rate can be calculated by the following formula:

> Churn Rate = 1 - Retention Rate

Is there some good reference around it as most of the google search leads to a definition and does not fully explain the mathematical relation between the two.